# Find particular file in particular directory

Tags: filesystems, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I want to find the particular file name in particular directory in ruby.

I tried the following Dir.glob()

```
file = Dir.glob("/home/prakash/Desktop/*.uploaded")
```

output:

```
/home/prakash/Desktop/abc.uploaded
```

But I just want only the file name in output. I don't want file name with fully path.

So how can I do this?

Comment: @ Dave Rook - abc.uploaded is the file name

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby, there is a file class.

```
File.basename("/home/prakash/Desktop/abc.uploaded")
```

The above will return `abc.uploaded`

Since I'm not sure if you want the extention or not, you can remove it using

```
File.basename("/home/prakash/Desktop/abc.uploaded", ".uploaded")
```

The above will return `abc`

[More reading](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/File.html#M000803)

Or you could perform a string manipulation

```
'/home/prakash/Desktop/abc.uploaded'.split('\\').last
```

Comment: Actually I don't know the file name on particular directory, I just know the extension of that file i.e. .uploaded, by using this extension i want to find the file name only without full path in prefix

Comment: So, the name `abc` could be anything? If so, the code above will work!

Comment: yes name abc could be anything. In you code you have given the fully path upto fine name to "File.basename()" class. But i don't know the file name, I know only the file extension then how can i do?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still a little lost - why don't you know the file name? If `Dir.glob(...` is returning the full path, then you do know it?

Answer (score 0):

I got easy way to find only file name without full path:

```
file = Dir.glob("/file/path/*.uploaded").join(" ")
filename = file.split('/').last
```

And it's working great for me